# Query to retrieve rows with no data even if not satisfying the where clause condition in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query two tables - TableA , TableB

Query :

```
select a.name, count(b.code)
from tableA a 
join tableA b on b.id = a.id 
where a.name = ('AA','BB','WWW') 
group by a.name;
```

The data is available only for AA so it displays the result as
`AA 5`

But i want to display the data as :

```
AA 5
BB 0
WWW 0
```

Comment: From the sound of it, it looks like you just need to change your JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and that should resolve your issue.  If it does not, please provide some sample data for the tables being used to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect expected names into separate table/subquery and then perform a left join with your data tables like

```
with exp_names as (
    select 'AA' name from dual
    union all
    select 'BB' from dual
    union all
    select 'WWW' from dual
)
select en.name, count(b.code)
from exp_names en
left join tableA a on en.name = a.name
left join tableB b on b.id = a.id
group by en.name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5abdbd6d04c9d3e8c895b19359d02e6e)